# PHPExcel setting date format without writing every single value

Tags: php, phpexcel, date-format

My current version of code for outputting to an Excel file is as follows:

I have an array of the column names and an array of all of the data:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($titleArr[$i]);                
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($headersArr[$i], NULL, 'A1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($dataArr[$i], NULL, 'A2');
```

The only other thing I've been doing is to autosize the columns

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                              ->getColumnDimension($col)
                              ->setAutoSize(true);
```

Is there any way to let the sheet be filled with data from the array and just tell excel that certain columns are actually in a specific format?

The following creates a custom field in Excel, rather than a date field.  It sorts but I have to manually tell it to treat it like a number.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($col . '2:' . $col. '500')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss');
```

Is there any way to get it to treat it like a date without having to write each cell manually with statements like:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, $currentrow, PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($timestamp));

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyleByColumnAndRow(3, $currentrow)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any such thing as a `date field` in Excel.... a date is nothing more than a number with a format mask.

But you could try using a cell binder: the cell binder is called whenever you set a value in a cell (unless you set the value explicit). The advanced value binder provided as an option with PHPExcel that recognises most date and time formats and will automatically convert and set a format mask accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If a whole column is filled with only date values, you can use `getStyle()` instead of `getStyleByColumnAndRow()` to get the whole column. Like this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C:C')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('dd/mm/yyyy');
```

A coordinate in the format `A:A` is converted to `A1:A1048576`. The same works for `1:1` which translates to `A1:XFD1`. See [`setSelectedCells()` in Worksheet.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/search?q=function+setSelectedCells&type=Code) for the different conversions.

Answer (score 0):

I put after `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray` to set date time in columns as shown below:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($row, null, "A".$red);

  // Again set row values
  $dateValuerr = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel(strtotime($row[NasDatumPrijemaPredmeti]));
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("D".$red."", $dateValuerr);

  $dateValuerr = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel(strtotime($row[NjihovDatumPrijemaPredmeti]));
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("E".$red."", $dateValuerr);

  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A".$red.":AF".$red)->applyFromArray($table_style);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A".$red.":AF".$red)->getFont()->setBold(true);
  $red++;
};
```

and then set column

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D2:E1000')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(exportdatum);

My date is : define('exportdatum', 'dd.mm.yyyy'); // Date
```

This is date in my MySql DB

```
MySql Date : 2015-05-01
But I convert in query to 

 DATE_FORMAT(predmeti.NasDatumPrijemaPredmeti, '%d.%m.%Y') AS NasDatumPrijemaPredmeti
```